# Navbar issue with sticky position

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
 window.onscroll= function() {myFunction()};

  var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
  
  function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    } else {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
  }
```

```html
<header id="home">
  <nav id="navbar">
    <div class="row flex">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" class="active">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service">service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team">team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skill">skill</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#review">review</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="hero-text-box">
      <h1>Hi there! We are the new kids on the block and we build awesome websites and mobile apps.</h1>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-hero">work with us!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Hello there, I am new to web development,after learning css and html I am doing some practice projects through youtube. That guy used a jquery plugIn that is not working correcting now. I have  googled and saw some youtube videos but no help there,it is important to know that I am a beginner in javascript, so I cannot do much with js part. Right now I am using the js code from w3school but it serves half of my demand. The issue is with navbar. I want to blend the navbar with the homepage but as soon as I scroll and reach certain point like other sections it will stick on the top.

Comment: do you have any css setting?

Comment: Can you share your styles (css)?

Comment: The javascript code only adds class to the navbar. It doesn't provide you with the class, so you have to define it in CSS.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap then no need to use jquery for sticky navbar. you can achieve this by bootstrap and javascript. Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Comment: .sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(115, 52, 146, 0.904);
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}                    here is the css

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify at what position you want to stick that bar. Position: Sticky works with some position where you want to stick that navbar. For Example:

```
position: sticky;
top: 3rem;
```

change your css from:

```
.sticky { 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
 }
```

to

```
.sticky { 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0; 
 }
```

Refer to this link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sticky_element

Try providing the top where you want to stick the bar while scrolling.
try with below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<style>
.sticky{
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}
</style>
<header id="home1">
  <nav id="navbar" class="sticky">
    <div class="row flex">
      <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt="logo"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" class="active">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service">service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team">team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skill">skill</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#review">review</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="hero-text-box">
      <h1>Hi there! We are the new kids on the block and we build awesome websites and mobile apps.</h1>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-hero">work with us!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
</html>
```

Comment: If I do that is does not work.And maybe you did get my question, let me explain, the navbar need to stick at the top as soon as I reach the next section after the homepage and if I came back it will blend with the homepage totally.

Comment: I think the above update code sticks to the top. Just copy paste the code in html and try, exclude the window.onscroll method and css in your code

Comment: @MdShohan, does the above answer worked or not ? if yes then please accept it as the answer.

Comment: No,I wish I could send you the link of the video,so you could understand what I want.